# How to read a specific line in a text file

Tags: powershell

I have hosts file that are on workstations that I need to read a specific line to get an IP Address. The ip address differs in location

This is the line that I have found to work the best.

**Get-Content hosts | Select-Object -Last 1**

Any way of parsing the text file for a specific word to read and output that 1 line?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you know what you are looking for, below will show you the matching lines in the file

```
Get-Content .\hosts | select-string 'searchstringhere' -SimpleMatch
```

Comment: You don't need the `Get-Content` for `Select-String`. That's like piping `cat` into `grep` ...

Comment: You don't need it in this particular case, but it matches OP's current code more closely and is arguably more expressive.  Just different parametersets of `Select-String`...

Comment: It's adding an unnecessary pipeline element. Usually that should be avoided. You also don't pipe `select` or `sort` to `gu`, do you?

Comment: Pipelines are never strictly necessary.  Using them provides a lot of benefits in usability (in the shell) and readability (in a script), though.  Unless you are tuning for performance, there is no harm at all in an additional pipeline element which provides more idiomatic or more readable code.  `Select-String` has an `InputObject` parameterset specifically to enable this.  Although it doesn't apply to this simple situation, sometimes you **need** to lead `Select-String` with `dir` and/or `gc` because you get more control over what files are processed and how they are read.

Comment: Also, you analogy doesn't really hold up.  `sort -unique | get-unique` is a *duplication of effort*.  Both cmdlets are doing work to filter unique objects.  `dir | select-string` or `gc | select-string` exhibit no duplication of effort at all. They simply allow each individual pipeline element to do less of the total work on its own.

Comment: I agree for `gci | select-string` but not for `gc | select-string`. And I meant that above in terms of leaving out the `-u` parameter to `sort` or `select`.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can use the following:

```
(Get-Content file.txt) -match '\d{1,3}(\.\d{1,3}){3}'
```

which should match an IPv4 address and yield the lines where one appears.